# Elementary OS on Lenovo Ideapad S10-2

Tags: lenovo

I own a Lenovo Ideapad S10-2 which runs slow on Windows XP. Tried to install Linux  some three years ago, but there were issues with the WiFi driver. Would you recommend installing Elementary OS on this platform? RAM has been upgraded to the max.
BR
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so familiar with the computer you have but as long as Windows XP runs slow probably it is not a good idea. What I recommend you is to make a live usb and try it, probably with some older version of the OS (http://osarchive.sda1.eu/elementary-os) because if I am not wrong, your computer is 32bit (i386) but all later versions of the elementary os are 64bit (amd64) and they will not run on your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Bo rislav is correct.  This computer has a 32 bit architecture, so no go for Elementary OS.  Given that, and slowness of the computer in general, I would look toward a super lightweight distro like LXLE.  It has a 32 bit version and a nice desktop.

As for the wi-fi (Broadcom?)  I am not sure of the current status, but they took a little fiddling in the past, but could be setup.  I would follow Bo rislav's recommendation and boot from a live key.  See if the Wifi works.  If not, I am sure an internet search might provide some solution.